# menubar nested buttons matlab

Tags: matlab, button, nested, menubar

i need to have some "sub-menu-buttons" appear when a top-level-menu-button is clicked, to be clear i need to create something like 'Brush/Select Data' button of the default figure toolbar.
[image: Brush/Select Data button image]

Do someone know how to do that? thank